# Customize PyCharm external tool notification

Tags: pycharm

I have created a custom tool in PyCharm and hid its console in settings because the tool is small and doesn't show a lot of info. When I run it, after it ends, there is a notification appears in the status bar on the left bottom saying 'External tool completed with code 0'. What I wonder about is if it's possible to customize this notification. Ideally I would like to read output from the tool and show a, e.g. balloon with some info. Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible with PyCharm, however you can use **Growl** for notifications, it's available on all platforms. Install it and call its command line tool to display pop-up notification from a batch script just after your tool finishes.

Comment: I have tried it with growlnotify.exe and it works fine. I think works fine for me. Thanks!